# From $L^p$ to $L^q$ Norm for finite trigonometric polynomial

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, fourier-series

Let $1\leq p\leq q \leq \infty$ and let $f\in L^p([0,2\pi])$ such that $\hat{f}(k)=0$ for all $\vert k\vert > N$. I would like to show that

$$\Vert f \Vert_p \leq (2N-1)^{1/p-1/q} \Vert f \Vert_q.$$

I managed to show the case $p=\infty$, $q=2$ using Young's Inequality for $f= f * g$, where $g$ is a function such that $\hat{g}(k)=1$ for all $k= -N,\ldots, N$ and zero otherwise, and Parseval Identity. How can I obtain the general case?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof generalises with little effort to a large number of pairs $(p,q)$ but not all of them. Young's inequality gives
$$ \| f * g \|_{L^p} \le \|f\|_{L^q} \|g\|_{L^r} $$
where $1+\frac1p = \frac1q +\frac1r$. The natural replacement for Parseval is (the dual inequality of) [Hausdorff-Young](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2537757/littlewood-paley-decomosition), which works for $r\ge 2$ i.e. $\frac12 + \frac1p \le \frac1q$, giving
$$ \|g\|_{L^r} = \|\mathcal F^{-1} \hat g\|_{L^r} \le \|
\hat g\|_{\ell^{r'}}, \quad \frac1r + \frac1{r'}=1 \iff \frac1{r'} = \frac1q - \frac1p$$
which gives $$\|g\|_{L^r} \le (2N+1)^{1/r'} = (2N+1)^{1/q - 1/p} $$ 
since $\hat g$ is supported on the $2N+1$ integers $|n|\le N$ where it takes the value $1$. (PS I think your inequality is not quite right)

This proof doesn't work when $\frac1q-\frac1p < \frac12$, and I suspect the result isn't true with constant 1 in this case since all sources I look at do not phrase it (Bernstein's inequality on the torus, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2537757/littlewood-paley-decomosition) and the referenced "EBP lecture notes on singular stochastic PDEs" by Gubinelli and Perkowski, pages 37 and onwards) with a constant 1. If one is prepared to lose a constant, then  [the computation here also finishes the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27517/lp-norm-of-dirichlet-kernel), since your $g$ is nothing but the Dirichlet kernel $g=\sum_{|k|\le N} e^{ikx}$.